# How to find an Ember object by its GUID? (retrieved using Em.guidFor)

Tags: ember.js

You can use `Ember.guidFor` to retrieve a GUID for an Ember object. It will return something like this:

```
"ember768"
```

Is there also a way to do this backwards (retrieving an object based on its GUID)?

I know that there is `Ember.View.views` which holds all Ember views indexed by its GUIDs. Something similar for any Ember object would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't. What is it you would like to accomplish? If you just want to see the contents of the object, you can use ember chrome extension.

Comment: No, it’s not for debugging. I’m currently integrating [DataTables](http://datatables.net) into Ember.js and need to know which object or model a table row is related to. I think it might be a good way to go to store that information in the DOM (using a `data-guid` attribute) so it can be accessed easily (e.g. after a click on a cell took place). So the solution is probably to have the TableView (which wraps DataTables) store a list of the items used with their corresponding GUIDs.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I'm doing the lookup. Still trying to see if there is a way to get at it more directly instead of looping through but it works.

```
DS.Store.reopen({
  findByGuid: function(type, guid) {
    return this.typeMapFor(type).records.find(function(item) { return Em.guidFor(item) == guid; });
  }
});
```

Usage as such:

```
store.findByGuid(MyModelType, "ember768");
```

HTH

N.B. Just to be clear, the above assumes you know the type of the object you're looking for. If you don't, one solution would be to iterate over the store.get('typeMaps') then iterate over each 'records' array. Seems a bit nasty to have to use N*N loops though!